# How to trim and process text strings with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html code:

```
<div class="item">[abc][def]...[xyz]</div>
```

I want to process to get results like this:

```
<ul>
<li>abc</li>
<li>def</li>
...
<li>xyz</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to do this with jquery?

Comment: Aside from selecting and replacing the content (eq using `$('.item').html()`), I don't think jQuery has something special for processing the content. What you want can be done with plain javascript though, using replace and regular expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Can you suggest me how to do it with javascript?

Comment: I've added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like below:

```
let content = $('.item').html();
content  = content.replace(/\[/g, '<li>').replace(/\]/g, '</li>');
$('.item').replaceWith(content);
```

I haven't tested this, but this should get you started. Note that the `replace` is plain javascript and a regular expression with `/g` is needed to replace all occurence: using simply `replace('[', '<li>')` for example would only replace the first occurence.

Also note that `.item` isn't a very specific selector. If you have multiple elements with this class, then you should wrap this logic inside an each-statement:

```
$('.item').each(function(){
   let content = $(this).html();
   content  = content.replace(/\[/g, '<li>').replace(/\]/g, '</li>');
   $(this).replaceWith(content);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const el = document.querySelector(".item");
const str = el.innerText.replace(/\]/g,' ').replace(/\[/g,' ')

const list = str.split(" ").filter(el => el !== "")
const ul = document.createElement('ul');

list.forEach(l => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = l;
  ul.appendChild(li)
})
el.appendChild(ul)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  var result = $(".item").text();
  
  result  = result.replace(/\[/g, '<li>').replace(/\]/g, '</li>');

$(".item").html('<ul>' +result + '</ul>' )
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="item">[abc][def]    [xyz]</div>

<button>Replace</button>


</body>
</html>
```